# Whats wrong with my dict?

Tags: python

I am running the following code to count how many times a word occured in a text file.

```
def print_words(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rU')
    dict={}
    for line in f:
       words=line.split()
       for word in words:
          if dict.get(word):
              dict[word]=dict[word]+1
          else: 
              dict[word]=1
    ke = sorted(dict.keys())
    for k, v in ke: print k, v
```

The dictionary file should hold each word and its count. I was able to get that working fine. But I failed to sort the

Comment: I think you accidentally the details.

Comment: btw, `dict` is a bad variable name, because it overwrites the `dict` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(dict.keys())` returns a sorted list of just the keys. Your for loop is incorrectly expecting to find the values in the same list. Try the code below instead:

```
for k in ke:
    print k, dict[k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers point out the problem. If you're using python 2.7+, here's an easier way to do it, using the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

def print_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        counts = Counter(f.read().split())
    for k, v in sorted(counts.items()):
        print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
ke = sorted(dict.keys())
for k, v in ke: print k, v
```

Try:

```
for k in sorted(dict.keys()):
    print k, dict[k]
```

`sorted(dict.keys())` will return a sorted list of only the keys (since that's all you're giving it).

Answer (score 1):

For a 2.5 and 2.6 compatible solution, use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(int)

for word in f.read().split():
    counter[word] += 1
```

This returns a dictionary (a subclass actually, but to be used the same way), where you can just look up `counter['someword']` (that returns an integer).

How it works: If the requested key does not exist, it is created using the return value of the given function. In this case, `int()`, which is `0`. See also the examples section at the documentation linked above.

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't answer OP's actual question.

Comment: Sure, for that's already been answered :) I just meant it as an addition to the Counter answer. (And it shortens his code by two lines ;) )

Comment: It only shortens the code because you've forgot opening the file and don't print out the sorted counts. Actually this needs an *extra* line: `counter = defaultdict(int)`. Upvoted anyway, I assume you'll fix the file opening at least.

Comment: The line you mentioned corresponds to the `dict = {}` line. But in fact it's probably less the shortness but the better readability. I left out the file and stuff to concentrate on the most relevant part.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you were comparing your code to mine, since you mentioned "the Counter answer". I see now what you mean, and which two lines (three, in fact) you were referring to.

Comment: Ah, oh, you're right, that's misunderstandable. I meant the OP with "shortens his code"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is more important - order or counting - you may use either [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or [counter dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the [collections module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html)

OrderedDict remembers the elements in the order they are added; Counter - counts elements

With the former, you may do something like that

```
>>> words = open(filename).read().split()
>>> counters = OrderedDict([(word, words.count(word)) 
                            for word in sorted(list(set(words)))])
```

You will get sorted dictionary with counters - just in 2 lines.

Comment: The efficiency of this solution is bad. `words.count(word)` is an O(n) operation which is called for every word, so the whole thing is O(n**2), even though only one pass over `words` is really needed to count all words. Using `Counter` is a much more efficient O(n) solution. If you wish to order the words by first seen, first count the words using `Counter`, then iterate over `words` using the [`itertools.unique_everseen` recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) and add the counts to an `OrderedDict`.